# ModelForm which takes either an Image or a URL and saves to an ImageField

Tags: django

I have a model which takes an image in an ImageField:

```
class Result(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_userphoto_upload_path)
```

I want a form that can take either a URL or an image, and will save the image to the model transparently.

This is what I'm thinking:

```
class ResultForm(forms.ModelForm):
  externalsource = forms.URLField(label='External URL', required=False)

  def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(ResultForm, self).clean()
    externalsource = cleaned_data.get('externalsource', False)
    if externalsource:
      req = requests.get(externalsource)
      image = StringIO(req.content)
      self.image.save(image)


  class Meta:
    fields = ['image']
    model = Result
```

I know the self.image.save(image) isn't correct (self.image does not exist) ... That's how I'd save the image manually if it was a Model rather than a Form. I'm not sure what I should use in its place.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd like to do *something* like the following. Note, I haven't run it or tested it or anything. But it should set you on the correct path hopefully.

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile

class ResultForm(forms.ModelForm):
  externalsource = forms.URLField(label='External URL', required=False)

  def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(ResultForm, self).clean()
    externalsource = cleaned_data.get('externalsource', False)
    if externalsource:
      req = requests.get(externalsource)
      image = StringIO(req.content)
      file = InMemoryUploadedFile(file=image, field_name=None, name=externalsource, content_type=req.content_type, size=req.size, charset=None)

      # Oops, long time since I used Forms, don't know how to do FileFields in forms
      # but something like you already wrote:
      self.image.save(name=dirname(externalsource), content=file)

  class Meta:
    fields = ['image']
    model = Result
```

So basically, only making an InMemoryUploadedFile and stuffing your image in there, -- and saving that in the ImageField.

Actually you can also simplify and use SimpleUploadedFile().

I also see now that you have another question embedded in there that is about Forms and Models and FileFields, -- I don't remember how to do that. :P